# Why is Google Maps .getCenter() returning invalid coordinates?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mobile-safari, user-agent

On a relatively high traffic site with users from all over the world, starting yesterday (2/13/2019), at approximately 5pm UTC we started to receive AJAX callbacks with invalid coordinates.

We have Javascript which detects when the map is idle and then sends the coordinates to our server for a reverse geocoder lookup. Here is a simplification:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mapObject, 'idle', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/geo/reverse/lookup',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 
      lat: mapObject.getCenter().lat(), 
      lng: mapObject.getCenter().lng() 
    }
  })
});
```

This has worked for a number of years without an issue. But yesterday we started receiving invalid lat/lng coordinates. This is causing the system we use to run the reverse geocoder lookup to complain. The majority of the invalid coordinates contain longitude values that are greater than `180`.

We have not been able to reproduce the issue in house. But I had a hunch that this was browser-related. Perhaps a new browser version was released and it is handling the Gmaps JS differently. So we started looking at the User Agents of the bad requests. The majority of the browsers are reporting agent `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1` however not ALL of the requests are Mobile Safari so I am not sure if this is a browser or a Gmaps issue.

I am hoping somebody can help shed some light on this or perhaps this will help others in a similar situation.

Comment: What about providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows to reproduce the issue and example data that we can test? Without that, I can't think of how anyone could help.

Comment: @MrUpsidown - we're not able to reproduce the issue unfortunately.

Comment: So you don't have any issue anymore? In that case I suppose you can delete this question.

Comment: No, we still have the issue. It is just not possible to reproduce locally. I am hoping that someone from the SO community has either run into the same issue or can help us to understand how we might be able to reproduce it since it only happening on a small sampling of our users' browsers. Thanks.

Comment: *yesterday we started receiving invalid lat/lng coordinates* - how do you know that then? Can you not log something and find out how/when this happens and why?

Comment: we know that starting on 2/13 `.getCenter().lng()` and `.getCenter().lat()` started outputting invalid coordinates in some users' browsers because those values are sent to us via an AJAX call to our `/geo/reverse/lookup` endpoint. we started getting errors in our logs stating that the coordinates are invalid (lng greater than 180, lat greater than 90, etc - all outside of normal bounds). We cannot reproduce this, but we know that the problem is affecting users as we're receiving 100's of errors per hour after years of never having a single, similar error. Hopes this helps to clarify.

Comment: Then you should log some values in your app that can help you find out what happens. Log the user browser, log the map bounds, zoom level, user position, etc. that should help you narrow the problem.

Comment: @MrUpsidown - that's exactly what we're doing. we have it narrowed down.. but just can't reproduce ourselves.

Comment: Did you not see my answer below?

Comment: @MrUpsidown - ah i do now. thank you!! :)

Comment: There is an update to the [bug in issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/124466802). It seems that it is working as intended for version 3.35 and 3.36 because these versions implement .getCenter() as notwrapped while for versions 3.33 and 3.34 they are wrapped. 
For the workaround of your issue you can check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the `getCenter` method with **versions 3.35 and 3.36** of the API. Version 3.34 works fine.

I am unable to get a latitude value of more than 90, but simply panning the map to the left or the right (in one direction) a few times shows **longitude values out of the -180 / 180 degrees range**.

I have opened a [bug report in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124466802).

```js
function initialize() {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.2,6.17);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    
      document.getElementById('lat').value = map.getCenter().lat();
      document.getElementById('lng').value = map.getCenter().lng();
    });
}

initialize();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.36&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
Lat: <input id="lat" type="text" /> Lng: <input id="lng" type="text" />
```

Here is the same code with **version 3.34** which works fine:

```js
function initialize() {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.2,6.17);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    
      document.getElementById('lat').value = map.getCenter().lat();
      document.getElementById('lng').value = map.getCenter().lng();
    });
}

initialize();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.34&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
Lat: <input id="lat" type="text" /> Lng: <input id="lng" type="text" />
```

Comment: ok, we've been just loading the API via `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=XXXXX` - will test this and get back to you. Cheers for finding this issue!

Comment: `v=3` is no longer reported as a valid way to [select the API version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions). You should use `weekly`, `quarterly` or a specific version instead. `v=3` falls back to quarterly version, which is 3.35, and which has the same issue.

Comment: I have replicated this in our environment. Going to define v3.34 explicitly and then check back in a few weeks to see if google has issued a fix so we can be on the `weekly` release.

Answer (score 1):

I've to do this function in order to patch the Google Maps bug:

```
const fixCoordinates = (coordinate: number) => {
  let fixedCoordinate = coordinate;
  while (fixedCoordinate > 180) fixedCoordinate -= 360;
  while (fixedCoordinate < -180) fixedCoordinate += 360;
  return fixedCoordinate;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked with version 3.35 and 3.36 and
it seems that getCenter() is not wrapped as per this [doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#LatLng) but does not happen in v 3.34.

This [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/35820436) also happened last 2011.

```js
function initialize() {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.2,6.17);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    
     // document.getElementById('lat').value = map.getCenter().lat();
     // document.getElementById('lng').value = map.getCenter().lng();
var center = map.getCenter();
var wrapped = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat(), center.lng());
document.getElementById('lat').value = wrapped.lat();
document.getElementById('lng').value = wrapped.lng();
    });
}
   initialize();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.36&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
Lat: <input id="lat" type="text" /> Lng: <input id="lng" type="text" />
```